# How to integrate latest version of stripe payment gateway (Server checkout) in angular-8?

Tags: angular, stripe-payments, angular8

I am using the latest version of angular which is Angular(v8.1.2). Now I need to integrate the latest version of stripe (API version 2019-05-16) payment gateway in my project. Specifically I want to add Server checkout payment of stripe.

I have tried to integrate using npm module @types/stripe but it's not working.

import * as Stripe from 'stripe';
const stripe = new Stripe("sk_test_B...");

It should work but getting the below errors ...
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stripe' in '/home/helal/Desktop/Angular/stripe-checkout/src/app'
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile

**UPDATE**

```
Finally, I have solved this issue.
1) My Front-end is Angular and created backend API in NodeJS
2) Created session id (stripe) in API (at backend, NodeJS)
3) Then using the session id, redirected to stripe hosted page from angular component ts file. I am giving example code below form more clarification.
```

**Bankend Code Example**

```
const stripe = Stripe('sk_test_*****************');

stripe.checkout.sessions.create(
  {
    success_url: 'http://localhost:4200/success',
    cancel_url: 'http://localhost:4200/cancel',
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items: [
      {
        name: 'T-shirt',
        description: 'Comfortable cotton t-shirt',
        amount: 1500,
        currency: 'usd',
        quantity: 2,
      },
    ],
  },
  (err, session) => {
    // asynchronously called
    res.send(JSON.stringify(session));
  },
);
```

**Frontend Code Example (_.component.ts file)**

```
// stripe session is the object returned from api
this.stripe_session = stripe_session; 
const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_*****************');
stripe.redirectToCheckout({
  sessionId: stripe_session.id
}).then(function (result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Visit [Stripe Hosted Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/server) Documentation for details.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. I also added a GET API endpoint to retrieve the session ID from my server, on success i then used the stripe.redirectToCheckout with that ID. Some additional info for others, make sure to import stripe.js in your index.html before the root div (React) and then in your react component access stripe with window.Stripe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Finally, I have solved this issue.***

```
1) My Front-end is Angular and created backend API in NodeJS
2) Created session id (stripe) in API (at backend, NodeJS)
3) Then using the session id, redirected to stripe hosted page from angular component ts file. I am giving example code below form more clarification.
```

**Bankend Code Example**

```
const stripe = Stripe('sk_test_*****************');

stripe.checkout.sessions.create(
  {
    success_url: 'http://localhost:4200/success',
    cancel_url: 'http://localhost:4200/cancel',
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items: [
      {
        name: 'T-shirt',
        description: 'Comfortable cotton t-shirt',
        amount: 1500,
        currency: 'usd',
        quantity: 2,
      },
    ],
  },
  (err, session) => {
    // asynchronously called
    res.send(JSON.stringify(session));
  },
);
```

**Frontend Code Example (_.component.ts file)**

```
// stripe session is the object returned from api
this.stripe_session = stripe_session; 
const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_*****************');
stripe.redirectToCheckout({
  sessionId: stripe_session.id
}).then(function (result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Visit [Stripe Hosted Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/server) Documentation for details.

Answer (score 4):

The `@types/stripe` package merely contains the type definitions for [Stripe API for Node JS](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/). It is not to be used on client side libraries or Frameworks, such as Angular.

If you want to implement Stripe.js and Stripe Elements, which are the client side JavaScript library for Stripe and UI components respectively, you should be following the instructions on the following [page](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/quickstart) instead. This will allow you to implement the client side payment flow on the front end.

Generally, how you should do it, is to add the following line on your index.html,

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```

In addition, you may wish to install the type definitions for [Stripe Checkout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/stripe-checkout) and [Stripe Elements](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/stripe-v3).

```
npm i @types/stripe-checkout
npm i @types/stripe-v3
```

And on the component that requires the usage of Stripe,

Add this on top of the declaration of your class/component.

```
declare var Stripe;
```

Then, you can mount the Stripe Elements

```
stripe;

ngOnInit() {
  this.stripe = Stripe('your_stripe_key');
  // do the rest.
}
```

If you want to find out more about it, you may refer to this 3rd party [tutorial](https://fireship.io/lessons/stripe-elements-angular/) as well.

Comment: Stripe-hosted page to accept payments is not possible in angular?

Comment: @Md.HelalUddin sorry for the late response, I just got back from vacation. You will need to handle the rest of the payment process (checkout session) on the server side!

Comment: Yeap! I did this. Thanks